# In Drupal 7 Views how do you set permissions via roles for an attachment display?

Tags: 7, views, users

I am trying to set roles permissions for my attachment view, but every time i set the roles permissions it affects the master display aswell. I want my attachment display only viewable to admin's of the site. Am i missing something or should is there another alternative to this issue?

[image]

Comment: this seems to be a possible views 3 bug as changing roles in one display affects the other even if you have setup the override. one solution i did was set my attachment access to "Permissions" and set my master to NONE for anonymous users.

Comment: By the way, the bug mentioned in the answer from duckx is https://drupal.org/node/1174588 There is a workaround, which is to override the access type as well as the permission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From you screenshot you gave permission to anonymous user, authenticated users and instructor. So the attachment will be visible to all users. Choose only admin for the attachment and for the page it is attached you do not need to set permissions. You settings should look something like the image below

[image]

[image]

Make sure you always apply permissions to the current display and not to all display.